# Gerrit Merge two commits

Tags: git, gerrit

I have this problem

```
master -> First commit (BROKEN) -> Second commit (Fix of previous commit)
```

How should I resolve the issue, (should not have happened, should have been an amend of the first commit rather than a second commit)?

can i amend/merge two commits in the gerrit gui somehow?

Not my commits, so don't have them locally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short:

No, you cannot merge them in Gerrit GUI. (you *could* write a plugin, if you really wanted).

The default way is to correct it locally (i.e. combine both commits using either `git rebase --interactive` or `git reset --soft HEAD~1; git commit`).

Then push the combined commit.

Finally, abandon the now obsolete (and marked as OUTDATED) second commit using the gui/website.

Comment: But then i have to download them separately from Gerrit right? Do I cherry pick both of them to a local branch?

Comment: If it were your commits, you should already have them locally. If not, yes, the easiest way could be to simply cherry-pick them both to a local branch.

Comment: Should have mentioned, not my commits

Comment: If they are from the same committer and depend on each other, it would be faster just to checkout the second (look for "depends on" in the details view of the second commit). However, I would make the most sense to let the original committer repair the commits. "teach them to solve their problems themselves"

Comment: Yes of course they should do it themselves, but I wondered if there was another way to do it, (e.g. the person is away from work)

Thanks anyway

Comment: I had two gerrits of my own, first one with lesser changes and the second one with additional changes to the same files. Second gerrit threw error of conflict and couldn't be merged together. Used the answer mentioned here and combined both changes into first gerrit and pushed again. Job done. Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of possible solutions depending on your detailed issue. But going to git shell would be the best starting point IMHO ;)

Based on your description my feeling is, that a rebaste interactive could help here. So

```
git rebase --interactive origin/master
```

A editor window will pop up where you can mark the fixing commit as fixup. Close the editor and both commits will be merged to one commit.

Instead of `origin/master`, which is the starting point for your rebase, you could also use something like `HEAD~2` which will start 2 commits before your current head.

Comment: But then i have to download them separately from Gerrit right? Do i cherry pick both of them to a local branch?

Comment: Yes, i think so. AFAIK it's not possible to do it inside gerrit and have to be done "upstream"